# In Ethereum, when assigning an address, it is throwing parsing error

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I was playing around with Ethereum studio, and tried to do some dummy data insertion on the bootstrap as shown below:

```
constructor () public {
        address x = 0XA48F2E0BE8AB5A04A5EB1F86EAD1923F03A207FD;
        address y = 0x95c2332b26bb22153a689ae619d81a6c59e0a804;
}
```

However I am getting below error:

```
Using Solidity compiler version 0.5.10
/contracts/HouseRegistrationContract.sol:31:21: ParserError: Identifier-start is not allowed at end of a number.
address x = 0XA48F2E0BE8AB5A04A5EB1F86EAD1923F03A207FD;
^
```

May I know what am I doing it wrong?
[ERROR] Ate bad code and died, compilation aborted.

Comment: Use 0х префикс for address, not 0X

Comment: Thanks @MadJackal However I am getting another error where it is saying the address is not valid.

`SyntaxError: This looks like an address but has an invalid checksum. Correct checksummed address:`

Comment: Yes, you must write the address exactly as it appears after the colon :-)
Select it with the mouse in the error message and, **without releasing the left key**, press CRTL + C. And then insert where necessary

Comment: Thanks. Manage to close it. Got the correct formatting from here: https://etherscan.io/address/0xa48f2e0be8ab5a04a5eb1f86ead1923f03a207fd